# c++ recursion help

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I am having trouble with recursion. Can anyone show me how to get this into code form?

given `vector <int>` with values 1,2,3,4,5,..

i want to write a function that compares all of the value with each other. i dont care about `1 != 2` being equivalent to `2 != 1` for now.

i am so bad at recursion

**and i promise that this is not homework**

**EDIT**
what i am trying to do is sort out events of a schedule. i have multiple events happening on the same day and i want to figure out all of the permutations of the schedule

2 nested for loops wont work since i am comparing multiple (>2) values

```
event 1 @ 0100-0230, or @ 0200-0330
event 2 @ 1200-1500, or @ 0800-1100
event 3 @ 1200-1300, or @ 1300-1400, or @ 1400-1500
.
.
.
```

for each comparion, i want to find out if that set of events intersect. i am not trying to find a set of events that all do not intersect

i want to get an output like

```
event 1 @ 0100-2300, event 2 @ 0800-1100, event 3 @ 1200-1300 // will be printed out
event 2 @ 0200-0330, event 2 @ 1200-1500, event 3 @ 1200-1300 // will be ignored
```

Comment: if it's not homework, what is it?

Comment: So write something, however bad, and show it to us.

Comment: If it is not a homework it is huge abuse of recursion. This is clearly iterative task.

Comment: You typically use recursion when traversing a tree-structure, which is not the case here. (You do know what *recursion* is, do you?)

Comment: It is really not clear what you want. Do you want to find duplicates? Do you want to know if all elements are the same? Please give an example with input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're investigating the relationship between recursion and iteration. Normally, simple iteration translates into tail recursion - the kind of recursion where recursive call is the last thing you do, so there is no need to have deep stack.

This is a bit of a pseudocode, plus it's not tested - but it should work.

```
void compareOne(int compareWith, iterator b, iterator e) {
    if (b == e) return;
    if (compareWith == *b) {
        // do something
    }
    compareOne(compareWith, b+1, e);
}


void compareAll(iterator b, iterator e) {
    if (b == e) return;
    compareOne(*b, b+1, e);
    compareAll(b+1, e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am betting this is homework... but I don't understand why you need recursion:

```
for(int i = 0; i<v.size(); ++i)
{
   for(int j = i+1; j < v.size(); ++j)
   {
      compare v[i] and v[j]
   }
}
```

Comment: `++i` or `++j` in the inner loop? :P

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need recursion? Simple iteration would do:

```
using namespace std;
vector<int> v;
...
for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < v.size(); j++)
        if (v[i] == v[j])
            cout << "Oops" << endl;
```

Or you can use iterators:

```
vector::const_iterator beforelast = v.end(); --beforelast;
for (vector::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != beforelast; ++i)
    for (vector::const_iterator j = i + 1; j != v.end(); ++j)
        if (*i == *j)
            cout << "Oops" << endl;
```

One *can* try to solve the problem with a recursion:

```
bool f(vector<int>& v, int lastidx)
{
    int lastval = v[lastidx];
    for (int i = 0; i < lastidx; i++)
        if (v[i] == lastval)
            return false;
    return f(v, lastidx - 1);
}
```

However, the non-recursive solution is better in my opinion.